# Create id from Ivar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am getting a list of all ivar using the following:

```
 Ivar *vars = class_copyIvarList([property class], &varCount);
```

My question is how do I create an id from an Ivar? I.e. recover an NSString or NSDictionary, etc.

Comment: Objective-C is not designed with this kind of dynamism in mind.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You just use `object_getIvar()` function.
Something like this:

```
uint varCount;
Ivar *vars = class_copyIvarList([property class], &varCount);

// Get the first one (out of an instance of this class)
// Of course you could just iterate and get each one
id var = object_getIvar(property, vars[0]);

// Free the array when you're done
free(vars);
```

Comment: This assumes the ivar is of type (id).  Note that object_getIvar() is effectively deprecated in that it really doesn't work for a lot of types.

Comment: @bbum Yes that is correct. I didn't know that and also saw Jonathan's comment. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

This approach could simplify your conversion code:

```
id obj = [p valueForKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:ivar_getName(anIvar)]];
...
```

Comment: This approach allows cleaner code than `object_getIvar()` because it will automatically box ivars whose types are not objects (for instance, an `int` ivar will be boxed in an `NSNumber`, a `struct` in an `NSValue`, etc.